# ¿Cómo selecciono el registro décimo de una consulta? Ejemplo, el décimo empleado con más salario

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Os pongo en contexto, necesito seleccionar el décimo país con mayor PIB.
PIB es una columna de una tabla. ¿Cómo podría realizar algo semejante?

Esto es lo que me piden en un trigger:

> Si se realizó un borrado en la tabla PAIS, deberá comprobar si el país
> eliminado es uno de los países de la tabla TOP_10_POTENCIAS_POR_PIB,
> en cuyo caso insertará el décimo país de mayor PIB de la tabla PAÍS en
> la tabla TOP_10_POTENCIAS_POR_PIB.

La tabla PAIS:

```
CREATE TABLE pais (   
cod_pais number(4),   
nombre varchar2(30),  
capital varchar2(20),  
 extension number(10),   
moneda varchar2(20),  
num_hab number(10),   
PIB number(20,2),   
continente varchar2(20),  
CONSTRAINT pk_pais PRIMARY KEY  (cod_pais));
```

¿Sé podría realizar con ROWNUM?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, pon la estructura de tus tablas y lo q has intentado

Comment: Ya la he editado

Comment: si, podes usar rownum y ordenar la tabla...

Comment: como podría hacerlo en este caso? ya que necesito el décimo pais con mayor pib, osea no el max

Comment: Para seleccionar el N registro segun un orden puedes usar la construcción ORDER BY + LIMIT N-1, 1
`SELECT * FROM pais ORDER BY PIB DESC LIMIT 9, 1;`

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final lo hice con un cursor, usando la función rowcount